# Quick question on error in python list * a constant e.g. [a , b, c, d , e ] * x

Tags: python, list

Quick question on a problem was doing previously. This question gives you a list of days from Mon - Sun, and you are supposed to create a list given 'n' (no of days ahead). So if n = 2, Monday will be Wednesday etc.

I tried this in python, and came up with this:

```
def after_n_days(days, n):
    day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'] * (int(n/7)+1)
    return [day[day.index(i) + n] for i in days]

after_n_days(["Monday","Friday","Wednesday"], 15)
```

However, it seems i get an error when i multiply the list 'day' by (int(n/7) + 1 when n= 15 and int(n/7) + 1 =3. It works when I simply multiply the list by 3 though, so I'm wondering what's the issue here?

Many thanks everyone!!

Here is the error message

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-481771160081> in <module>
      6 
      7 
----> 8 after_n_days(["Thursday", "Monday"], 4)
      9 after_n_days(["Monday","Friday","Wednesday"], 15)

<ipython-input-124-481771160081> in after_n_days(days, n)
      3 def after_n_days(days, n):
      4     day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'] * (int(n/7)+1)
----> 5     return [day[day.index(i) + n] for i in days]
      6 
      7 

<ipython-input-124-481771160081> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 def after_n_days(days, n):
      4     day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'] * (int(n/7)+1)
----> 5     return [day[day.index(i) + n] for i in days]
      6 
      7
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please post the traceback message showing the error.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: I ran your code and the function returned `['Tuesday', 'Saturday', 'Thursday']`. Is that the value you wanted?

Comment: man works for me in python 2.x and 3.x !!

Comment: Oh really, i was using 3x in Jupyter. Error length too long, will post in original question. Thanks !!

Comment: I think that the confusing part of this question is that you posted a working example. Use the failing `after_n_days(["Thursday", "Monday"], 4)` instead. Also, the formula for expanding the list is off the screen on the right. Could could add a newline to keep the code in the window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't expand the list far enough. Multiplying a list by 1 is just the list. Any day, n combination that goes off the end of the list fails. For example,

```
after_n_days(["Thursday", "Monday"], 4)
after_n_days(["Thursday", "Monday"], 7 + 4)
etc...
```

You could just make the expanded list bigger

```
day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 
        'Saturday', 'Sunday'] * (int(n/7)+2)
```

Or better, use the modulo operator to wrap the index instead.

```
def after_n_days(days, n):
    print(int(n/7)+1)
    day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 
            'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    return [day[(day.index(i) + n) % len(day)] for i in days]

after_n_days(["Thursday", "Monday"], 4)
after_n_days(["Monday","Friday","Wednesday"], 15)
after_n_days(["Monday","Friday","Wednesday"], 18)
```